# Android, error='Network is unreachable' при попытке подключения к серверу из NDK

Tags: сеть, boost, android-ndk

Есть такой С++ код в NDK:

```
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("xx.xx.xx.xx"), 44550);
    sock.connect(ep, ec);

    LOGI("out2: ec=%s\n", ec.message().c_str());

}
```

Но в выводе получаю: `out2: ec=Network is unreachable`

Если же этот код скомпилить и выполнить на PC - все ОК.

В манифесте приложения указано `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Идеи?

ps
тестирую на эмуляторе.

psps
в качестве NDK используется `crystax-ndk-10.3.2-linux-x86_64`

Comment: Можете посмотреть IP адрес своего устройства в эмуляторе?

Comment: @user1056837 как это сделать?

Comment: зайдите в настройки сети в эмулируемом устройстве и там будет IP-адрес.

Comment: @user1056837 а, вы об этом. говорит что `Unavailable`.

Comment: Как я понимаю, зайти из браузера в эмуляторе вы тоже никуда не можете. Так?

Comment: могу. т.е. в браузере инет есть.

Comment: Посмотрите из `adb shell` , что покажет `ifconfig`

Comment: странно все это... установил `adb-tools`. ось попросила перезагрузку. перезагрузился - все ок. спасибо за ваше время!

Comment: бред какой-то. перезапустил эмулятор, и снова все по старому, `Network is unreachable`

Comment: А какая хостовая ОС?

Comment: linux. вот что говорит `ifconfig`: http://pastebin.com/32a9dd4x